# What does "run" in "Run the world" mean?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, lyrics

I saw the image below:

[image]

It's a reference to Beyonce (how you can see at the title [here](https://br.pinterest.com/pin/712272497286704404/)), her song is called *Run The World (Girls).*

Inside the context of the song. How about this substitution?

"Who order/boss the world? Girls"

Does *run* mean this? and **Why was this word picked and not others?**

And if you know, other use for *run*. Not like *run* in a race/the *run* actividade. Other uses and meanings, not the most common.

Answer (score 4):

In your usage

> run

means to control, organize, and coordinate the operations of an entity.  It is usually used to describe

> The smooth *running* of a company and its operations.

Your example is saying that the world is *controlled* by girls.